# HTML form focus

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do i simulate enter key pressed to behave like tab. I would not like to use jQuery. I simply need to blur(loose focus) on current input (textfield) and focus on next (input) element. I tried this but it doesn´t work.

```
const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
const keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
 if (event.target.value !== '' && keyCode === 13) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.blur();
  event.target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: 'Tab' }));
   }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger default browser behaviour by simulating events.

You'll need to identify the next field in the tab order, find it in the DOM, then call its `focus()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keydown', ':tabbable', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13  || e.keyCode == 13  ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $canfocus = $(':tabbable:visible')
        var index = $canfocus.index(document.activeElement) + 1;
        if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;
        $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
    }   
});
```

> [Example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Parth_Raval/mkeonLn3/)

Comment: The questioner mentioned, he doesn't want to use Jquery. But keep this answer alive for future.

Comment: This will navigate in DOM order ignoring `tabindex` based order changes.